# Tilde in a image path

Tags: graphics, xetex

I have a problem with a path to a image. The image path looks like this:

```
\includegraphics[]{C:/Users/JOHN~1.WEL/AppData/test.png}
```

If i put mouse over the image path it shows up but when i try to compile give me some error because of "~". The entire username is JOHN.WELSH

Error is:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. ^^I^^I}{}
```

I don't hava alternatives. The path to the image is given in this way(are added automaticaly). How can i add this image in my document using this type of path?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `~` is an active character (i.e. is actually a macro) the file path is not a normal string. You need to place a string version of `~`. This can be done by appending the TeX primitive `\string` in front of it.

The following should do it:

```
\includegraphics[]{C:/Users/JOHN\string~1.WEL/AppData/test.png}
```